# in Lua 5.x what is Lua 4.0 "gettable" and "settable" event used to set tagmethods (like metamethods)?

Tags: lua, meta-method

In lua 4.0 the tagmethod "gettable" allows to intercept the access to table elements.
Each time there is an attempt to access a table element, the linked tagmethod for "gettable" event is called:

```
local t = { a=123 }
local tg = newtag()
settagmethod(tg, "gettable", 
  function(tbl, idx) print(tbl, idx) return rawget(tbl, idx) end )
settag(t, tg)
print(t.a)    -- <-- prints table: 0x7f9a8250acc0   a
              -- <-- then prints t.a value
```

What is the equivalent in Lua 5.xx ?

How can my code call a method each time the table is accessed in Lua 5.x?

Comment: In Lua 5.x you need [proxy table](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.4.html)

Comment: Egor is right. My answer (now deleted) was incorrect. `__index` is called only when a caller attempts to access a `nil` element. `t[data]` in my answer was wrong! It was actually `nil`. I had defined `t.data` and `t.data` is equivalent to `t[“data”]`, not `t[data]`. But that leads to why you need a proxy table: If the table that is available for accesses is completely empty, then __index and __newindex metamethods will ALWAYS intercept. Then those methods can access a different table that is otherwise not visible.

Comment: @brianolive, yep, I figured out why __index event metamethod was not working with tbl[data]  but with tbl.data.
@ Egor Skriptunoff, I used a proxy table, it's the easier solution as "settable" event doesn't exist in Lua 5.x .... was useful tho in 4.0.   Anyway I ended using a proxy table as well for another pieace of code in 4.01. 
Thanks.